# Base and child classes models in 2 different indipendent tables

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm supposed to cache incoming data. I have 2 models OrderModel and OrderDetailedModel, where OrderModel is a base class and OrderDetailedModel a child class.

The user firstly opens a list of orders - only some data is being retrieved (a list of Order models). This list should be cached.

When the user selects a particular order all the information is being (OrderDetailedModel) and this also should be cached.

The important thing is I don't want the cached OrderDetailedModel row to be overwritten by OrderModel when the list is downloaded again. (don't want to clear details information)

I tried to create 2 different DbSets:

```
public DbSet<OrderModel> Orders { get; set; }
public DbSet<OrderDetailedModel> OrderDetails { get; set; }


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetailedModel>().Map(m =>
    {
        //m.MapInheritedProperties(); // this doesn't help either
        m.ToTable("OrderDetails");
    });

modelBuilder.Entity<OrderModel>().Map(m =>
        {
            //m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Orders");
        });

}
```

But it seems they still are connected somehow. This is the "content" of each DbSet:

Order:

```
FROM  [Orders] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
    .....
    cast(1 as bit) AS [C1]
    FROM [OrderDetails] AS [Extent2] ) AS [Project1] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Project1].[Id]}
```

OrderDetails:

```
{SELECT 
N'0X0X' AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
... 
[Extent1].[StoreContact] AS [StoreContact], 
...
FROM  [OrderDetails] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [Orders] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]}
```

This results in an error:

```
var a = Entry<T>(detailedOrderObject);
```

> "System.InvalidOperationException: The entity found was of type
>   OrderModel when an entity of type OrderDetailedModel was requested.

This happens because detailed order has the same Id ad one of the orders downloaded in a list. (Ids come from server)

Which is the right way to go here?

- 2 totally separate and indipendant tables. How to do this?
- Put everything in detailed order table. Again, how to do this to avoid overwriting I mentioned above?
- Maybe something else?

**EDIT**

Models' classes:

```
public class OrderModel
    {
        [Key, Column(Order=0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "order_id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "order_number")]
        public String Number { get; set; }

        //... only properties, like the one above

public class OrderDetailedModel :OrderModel
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="store_contact")]
        public string StoreContact { get; set; }

        //... only properties, like the one above
```

Comment: Can you please post the code for Orders and for OrderDetails?

Comment: @IronMan84 Sure thing. Though I'm afraid there's nothing interesting in them. See edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes are still connected because your OrderDetailedModel class is derived from OrderModel, and EF is getting confused when you're querying the table.

That being said, I think you should absolutely split them off into 2 separate tables, if for no other reason other than to normalize your database. To split it off, you'll need to include the ForeignKey attribute to your code, and stop having the OrderDetailedModel class be derived from OrderModel.

Assuming that OrderModel : OrderDetailedModel is a 1:1, here is what you would do:

Add this to OrderModel:

```
public virtual OrderDetailedModel OrderDetails { get; set; }
```

And for your OrderDetailedModel have the following (any other annotations, like the JsonProperty ones can be kept as well--I'm just showing you the EF ones that you'll need to have):

```
public class OrderDetailedModel
{

  [Key, ForeignKey("Order")]
  public int OrderID { get; set; }

  //some properties

  public virtual OrderModel Order { get; set; }

}
```

Let me know how that works.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody needs to keep inheritance, I'm posting a workaround I created:

```
public class OrderModel
{
    protected bool _detailed;

    [Key, Column(Order=0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "order_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public bool Detailed
    {
        get { return _detailed; }
        set
        {
            if( (this.GetType() == typeof(OrderModel) && value== true) ||
                (this.GetType() == typeof(OrderDetailedModel) && value==false))
                throw new ArgumentException("This property is restricted");
            _detailed = value;
        }
    }

    //....

    public OrderModel()
    {
        _detailed = false;
    }
}


public class OrderDetailedModel :OrderModel
{
    //.....

    public OrderDetailedModel()
    {
        _detailed = true;
    }
}
```

It's not beautiful, but works.